# TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [auth/login]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

i faced this problem , when i send request with invalid user credentials.
If user credentials are valid , everything works normal.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/")
public class AuthenticationRestController {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationRestController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, UserService userService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    @ResponseBody
    public AuthenticationResponseDTO login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequestDTO requestDto) {
        try {
            String email = requestDto.getEmail();
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, requestDto.getPassword()));
            userService.findByEmail(email);

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(email);

            return AuthenticationResponseDTO.builder()
                    .token(token)
                    .email(email)
                    .build();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

WebSecurity config

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/auth**",
                        "/auth/login**",
                        "/registration/**/**",
                        "/password/restore**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/assets/**",
                        "/error**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();

    }
```

if i send success request,

```
{
    "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "password" : "test"
}
```

i get this

```
{
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJVU0VSIiwiRU5URVJQUklTRV9VU0VSIiwiTU9ERVJBVE9SIiwiQURNSU4iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTcyOTQ0Mzg0LCJleHAiOjE1NzI5NDc5ODR9.D1RCgT9xI1EavnHvKVs2vB9RjnxUXQ3z9Ne9hxcIa60"
}
```

But if i send bad credentials :

```
{
    "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "password" : "wrong"
}
```

i get this :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-05T09:01:30.291+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid username or password",
    "trace": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:...
}
```

that is OK ,BUT i get Error in my logs

```
**org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [auth/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers**
```

Can someone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution , but still don't know why it works like this.

I add this configuration ,and now have no errors

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> webServerCustomizer() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/"));
    }
}
```

Please can someone explain me what was my problem?)